# Doctrine2 + Symfony2 with default Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, symfony, reference, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working on a model, which doesn't quite satisfy me yet. I got a set of Objects with single-inheritance, which reference another object:

```
class Category
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto") */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDB\Int */
    protected $categoryId;

    /** @MongoDB\String */
    protected $title;
}

class ProductTypeOne extends BaseProductType
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto") */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDb\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Category") */
    private $category;     

}
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment, when I create an object ProductTypeOne, I actually know which category it will reference - it's always the same for this ProductType.

I could set a fix parameter, like `category_id = 1` - but the architecture within Sf2 & Doctrine2 doesn't allow me to query for the Category Object from within my Entity (Document, as i'm using MongoDB).

```
class ProductTypeOne 
{

    private $category_id = 5;

    public method getCategory()
    {   
       /** how to query the CategoryObject with ID=5? */
    }
}
```

Open for any input, thank's in advance!

Comment: Inject the known category in the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: Was trying with the constructor too, but doesn't solve the problem completely. 
This requires me to pass it to the constructor, but i don't want to grab those related items every time i use the Subclass in a controller.. 

I've been reading with DI/Services Architecture of Symfony aand will give it a shot later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this then:

```
class ProductTypeOne extends BaseProductType
{

    static $DEFAULT_CATEGORY = 5;

    // rest of the code

}
```

At insertion time [in the controller], you set the category:

```
$product = new ProductTypeOne;

// do whatever you need to fill the instance

$product -> setCategory(
    $this -> getDoctrine() -> getRepository('Category') -> findOneById( ProductTypeOne::$DEFAULT_CATEGORY )
);

// persist $product, beer time
```

Another approach would be writing you custom `ProductTypeOneRepository`, and inject the category in its methods.